# How does BUSY_TIMEOUT works in SQLITE

Tags: c, database, sqlite

I have some confusions regarding BUSY_TIMEOUT for sqlite 3.

1. If I set a busy_timeout when I open a database, then will it survive during whole cycle?
2. Secodly if it survives, then will it make every query to wait for BUSY_TIMEOUT time in case the database is locked?

Answer (score 0):

1. The busy_timeout setting is per session, i.e., you need to set it exactly once per opened database.
2. The database will wait when it tries to lock the database file, i.e., when you have the first read or write access in a transaction, or when you use an explicit lock.